# fetch result from the query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP25
(
  STATUS  VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
);

Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('PENDING');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('ERROR');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
  ('ERROR');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('ERROR');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('NOT_REQUIRED');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('NOT_REQUIRED'); 
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('PENDING');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
   ('PENDING');
Insert into TEMP25
  (STATUS)
 Values
   ('ERROR');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
Values
  ('NOT_REQUIRED');
Insert into TEMP25
  (STATUS)
 Values
  ('ERROR');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS)
 Values
  ('INVALID');
Insert into TEMP25
   (STATUS) 
 Values
   ('INVALID');
Insert into TEMP25
  (STATUS)
 Values
  ('PENDING');
```

I want to write a query such that i get count like

```
TOTAL_RECORDS  TOTAL_PENDING TOTAL_NOT_REQUIRED   TOTAL_PENDING
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   14               4             3                   5 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the record in  sequence and in  one query , i ahve tried with `with table` clause it works ...is there any other solution ...and dnt want invalid records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SUM/CASE` or (`SUM/DECODE` if you prefer)

```
Select
   COUNT(*) TOTAL_RECORDS  ,
   SUM(case when status = 'PENDING' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_PENDING, 
   SUM(case when status = 'NOT_REQUIRED' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_NOT_REQUIRED, 
   SUM(case when status = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_ERROR


FROM temp25
```

[See it working here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3feb/4)

You can also use pivot but getting the count(*) is a little ugly

```
WITH 
COUNTS AS(
select * 
from (
   select status
   from TEMP25 t
)
pivot 
(
   count(status)
   for status in ('PENDING' AS TOTAL_PENDING,
                  'NOT_REQUIRED' AS TOTAL_NOT_REQUIRED,
                  'ERROR' AS TOTAL_ERROR)
))


SELECT COUNT(*) total_records, 
       total_pending, 
       total_not_required, 
       total_error 
FROM   temp25, 
       counts 
GROUP  BY total_pending, 
          total_not_required, 
          total_error
```

[Pivot version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3feb/18)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make use of case when statement and get this result ...have look to it also...

```
Select    COUNT(*) TOTAL_RECORDS  ,    
SUM(case when status = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_ERROR   
SUM(case when status = 'NOT_REQUIRED' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_NOT_REQUIRED,     
SUM(case when status = 'PENDING' then 1 else 0 END) TOTAL_PENDING,  
FROM temp25
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP25) total,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEMP25 WHERE STATUS='PENDING') pending,
[...]
FROM dual ;
```

All databases have a null table you can use from this kind of thing.

Comment: the previous answers have the advantage of single scan of souce table.