# Merging matching data side by side from different tables

Tags: sql

I have a select statement that gathers data from one monthly-summary table like the following

```
companyname, employee, id, usage_a, ... usage_m
```

I need to create report from 6 monthly-summary tables that looks like the following

```
companyname, employee, id, 
jan_usage_a, ...june_usage_a, average (jun_jan_usage_a), 
...  
jan_usage_m, ...june_usage_m, average (jan_jun_usage_m)
```

I have done something similar with less columns, but i had to create a table with columns for each month's usage and then merge data in month to month with a single query. At the end I would export to excel create another column to average the each usage over the months required.

For the report above I'd have to create a table over one hundred columns. 
My question is is there a better way to do this? 
Thanks.

Sorry for the title if it's a little unclear.

Comment: Sounds like you want to do a pivot. Every database can do it but the implementation is very much tied to the RDMBS. Also without table structure sample data and expected output it would be difficult to provide an answer.

Comment: @Conrad, I did the query as Gordon suggested then did the pivot in excel. Doing that saved me a lot of time and it came out how the customer wanted it. Thanks for your pivot suggestion.

Comment: well I'm glad it helped but it was an accident :). I actually didn't mean the Excel Pivot but rather pivoting in the Database. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222480/119477).

Comment: :) Oh. I'll definitely look back at that job and try that pivoting method. Thanks for the clearing that up and the link provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have six different tables, then you need to join them together:

```
select tjan.companyname, tjan.employee, tjan.id, <rest of tjan columns>, <rest of jfeb columns>
from tjan join
     tfeb 
     on tjan.companyname = tfeb.companyname and
        tjan.employee = tfeb.employee and
        tjan.id = tfeb.id
etc. etc. etc.
```

The problem that you have is that the populations in the different months may be different, so the joins will lose rows.  A good way to handle this is with a driving table:

```
select . . .
from (select companyname, employee, id from tjan union
      select companyname, employee, id from tfeb union
      . . .
     ) driving left outer join
     tjan
     on tjan.companyname = driving.companyname and
        tjan.employee = driving.employee and
        tjan.id = driving.id left outer join
     tfeb
     on tfeb.companyname = driving.companyname and
        tfeb.employee = driving.employee and
        tfeb.id = driving.id left outer join
    . . .
```

You can do all this in one SQL statement.  There are repetitive parts (such as the column names in the select).  Consider using Excel to generate these.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the detailed response and the quick timing of it. I'll look into this solution. By the way, I picked up a copy of your book Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel to help me with my job and it has so far.